# How to check which <button> was clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am using `<button>` instead of `<input>` because I need to contain an image in the buttons. This makes the form submit behavior different. How do I check which button the user clicked?  There is no post data returned.

Example:

```
<button onclick="this.form.submit()" value="Done" name="Done"><img src='...'></button>
<button onclick="this.form.submit()" value="Save" name="DSave"><img src='...'></button>
```

Comment: Tip: inside a form a buttons default type is submit. So actually these should function the same.

Comment: Ah, I had an extra field type='Button' that was keeping it from submitting.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the `onclick` attributes. Let the button's natural submit feature submit the form instead of using JS. This will make the clicked button a successful control and it's name/value will appear in the submitted data.

Answer (score 0):

Use a hidden input to carry the value, if POST isn't working

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `<submit>` and that field name will be sent with the `value` `Done` or `Save`...

Comment: You mean `<input type="submit">` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `<input type="submit">` and just style them with css. In this way you can assign values to input.

Comment: The question is specific to sending post data with Button instead of using input.

Comment: Yes, but you said it's because you need to show images inside of the button. It's why I recommend using css to put this images as background. This solution is more cross browser compatible. In IE < 8 it will not submit value, but text inside of the `buttton` tags. so in this case probably `<img>` tag

Comment: I am already using a background image as well as an additional image as part of the content.

Comment: Still you can jus wrap it in div with image background. It will still be more Cross browser compatibile.